# fill null values from another table with the same dimensions

Tags: sql, hive

I have two table e.g.

First table:

```
| A | B    |  
|---|------|  
| 3 | 2    |  
| 1 | NULL |
```

Second table:

```
| A | B    |  
|---|------|  
| 0 | 9    |  
| 7 | 5    |
```

They have the same columns with the same order, and the same number of rows. I need to fill NULL values of the first table with values from the second table corresponding to the same cell, so that the first table becomes

```
| A | B    |  
|---|------|  
| 3 | 2    |  
| 1 | 5    |
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Why? I can't see any reason to do that.

Comment: @gordon-linoff actually I have one, and it's id

Comment: @jarlh I have data for some timestamp, it's the first table, I need this timestamp, but some values are missing, so I take newer values, because it's better than missing values

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column that specifies the ordering in each table, you can use `join` and `row_number()`:

```
select t1.a, coalesce(t1.b, t2.b) as b
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 left join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

This is a bit challenging to represent as an `update` in Hive.  I would recommend saving the results as a temporary table and then overwriting the original table.